# Python Map() reverse

Tags: python

Is there a function that takes a list of functions and an input and outputs a list of the functions operation on the input?

So like `map`, but backwards:

```
>>>map(lambda x: 2*x,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>>reverseMap([lambda x: x**2,lambda x: x**3],3)
[9,27]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can in fact use a `map` to do this:

```
>>> map(lambda f: f(3), [lambda x: x**2,lambda x: x**3])
[9, 27]
```

Use the list of functions you want to apply as the iterable, and then apply each of them to your input (in this case 3).

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> funcs = [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3]
>>> 
>>> [f(3) for f in funcs]
[9, 27]
```

Answer (score 4):

How about simply:

```
In [1]: [f(3) for f in lambda x: x**2,lambda x: x**3]
Out[1]: [9, 27]
```

You can wrap it in a function if you like.